# Converting "in place" a column of cells from minutes to hours and minutes in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have several columns of data in an Excel 2010 worksheet that are values in minutes and I want to convert them to hours and minutes (the data source will only generate an Excel workbook using minutes).

How can I convert these values *in place* to a text string that is hours and minutes.

For example, if I have a cell `F1` containing a value `300` and drop this formula into into the same cell I get a circular reference error:

```
=INT(F1/60)&" h "&MOD(F1,60)&" m"
```

I could hide the cells containing the raw values and have a second column that has the formula that does the conversion, but it means an awkward extra step for five long columns of numbers.

Is there a way to do this without creating extra cells to hold the calculated value?

Comment: The short answer is "no" if you're committed to using only worksheet functions. However, if you're open to using VBA, a very simple macro can do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Excellll; you're going to need VBA to convert the values in place to a string value.

This method won't result to text strings; but it might help you get the format you need.

Let's say these were my minutes:

[image]

1. Type `1440` into any blank cell. Select this cell and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.
2. Select the range that contains the minutes.
3. **Paste Special** > **Values** > **Divide**
4. Click **OK**. Result:

   [image]
5. Select the range of number again and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>.
6. Go to **Number** > **Custom**
7. Type the format:

   `[h] "h" mm "m"`

Result:

[image]

If you'd like to change them back to minutes:

1. Type `1440` into any blank cell. Select this cell and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.
2. Select the range that contains your hours/times.
3. Paste Special > Values > Multiply.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>. Set the number format back to **General**.
5. You may get rid of the 1440 cell when you're done.

To get the number of hours in decimal form, use `60` instead of `1440`. So for 330 (mins), you'll get 5.5 (hours).

Comment: Brilliant!...I didn't know you could do that "paste special and divide". I did write a VBA macro, but because macros have to belong to a workbook I had to recreate it every time I did an export from Jira. Also the number of rows varies depending on the number of project tasks etc etc. And PM's need to be able to work this as well :). Very neat, thanks.

Comment: You might find this article useful too: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/deploy-your-excel-macros-from-a-central-file-HA001087296.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The circular reference is because you are trying to run the formula on the cell the data is in. You need to place the formula in a different cell so it can calculate the results. If you don't want to see the first cell (total minutes), you can hide the column. I tested this with 300 in F1 and placing your formula in F2 and it works properly.

Comment: As I stated in my question, I already know how to do that.